# Wordpress and mssql-php in docker

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, docker

I'm looking for a best practice or good way to create a docker system with WordPress and MS SQL server, PHP drivers because I'm going to access MS SQL databases from WP plugins.
Until now I tested this images:

https://hub.docker.com/r/lbosqmsft/mssql-php-msphpsql/

https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Both do what I need, my question is: should I link them, or modify one of the docker files to include the other? Is it possible the link?

Any suggestion and examples of docker files or compose will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Diego

Answer (score -1):

WordPress does NOT support SQLServer officially.

If you insist to, you can try to use this one: https://projectnami.org/ and forget the dockers you found.

Comment: Thanks. I'm developing a custom plugin for WP using PHP, son I don't need that WP support it.